# Circular Doubly-Linked List indexOf and remove functions incorrect

Tags: java, intellij-idea, data-structures, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

I am currently implementing a circular doubly-linked list with a dummy head node. My add functions (adding an element at a given index, at the start, or at the end) seem to work flawlessly, but I cannot extrapolate to make a functioning indexOf (which returns the index of an element) or remove (remove node at given index) method.

When debugging, indexOf seems to grab the wrong index. When given a list of:

```
[Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, Wyoming, California]
```

Calling

```
list.remove(indexOf("Wyoming"));
```

Returns

```
[Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, Wyoming, ]
```

Here is the indexOf function:

```
public int indexOf(E e) {
    Node<E> current = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (e.equals(current.element)) {
            return i;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And here is the remove function:

```
public E remove(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    } else if (index == 0) {
        return removeFirst();
    } else if (index == size - 1) {
        return removeLast();
    } else {


        Node<E> previous = head;
        for (int i = 1; i < index; i++) {
            previous = previous.next;
        }
        Node<E> current = previous.next;
        previous.next = current.next;
        size--;
        return current.element;

    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you change your `for(...)` loop from `i < index` to `i < index-1`

Comment: This breaks it even further; it fails previous tests if I change i < index to i < index - 1

Comment: When you say you have a dummy head node, do you mean that `head` is never null? Is the element referenced by `head` the first element in the list, or is `head.next` the first element of the list?

Comment: Head should always be null, and head.next should be the first element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

If `head` should always be `null`, then your `indexOf()` method doesn't seem correct

```
public int indexOf(E e) {
    Node<E> current = head.next; // Add this to effectively begin with the first index of your list
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (e.equals(current.element)) { // This will never be equals, because of the first time current being null
            return i;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
    return -1;
}
```